# Error with php code, error displayed Undefined Offset

Tags: php

this line of code keeps getting me undefined offset: on line 9. I have no idea whats wrong with it, the codes runs smoothly but this part of the code is getting me undefined offset. i believe its something with $i

```
for( $i = 0; $lines[$i]; $i++ ) /** LINE 9 **/
{
if( $_POST['Aut'] == rtrim($lines[$i]) )
{
    fwrite($file, $_POST['addition']."\n\t");
    fwrite($file, $_POST['Aut'].PHP_EOL);

}
else
{
    fwrite($fd,$lines[$i]);
}
```

Comment: `$lines[$i]` really? This is your condition of the for loop? What is in `$lines` show us the output of a print_r() call

Comment: There must be -> for( $i = 0; $i<=$lines[$i]; $i++ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for( $i = 0; $lines[$i]; $i++ )
```

When does the loop end? One iteration too late. It has to be

```
for( $i = 0; $i<count($lines); $i++ )
             ^
```

**[For Loop Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php)**

Comment: Don't has to be the case, maybe OP has a false value in the array like this: `$lines = array(1, 2, 3, 4, false, 5);`

Comment: Nope. If the loop never ends it will go beyond range fast

Comment: It ends if he has a false value in the array

Comment: Thanks Hanky panky! this worked for me, ill check this as the answer to my solution as soon as it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
foreach($lines as $line) /** LINE 9 **/
{

    if( $_POST['Aut'] == rtrim($line) )
    {
        fwrite($file, $_POST['addition']."\n\t");
        fwrite($file, $_POST['Aut'].PHP_EOL);

    }
    else
    {
        fwrite($fd,$line);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the else there's still `$lines[$i]`

Answer (score 0):

```
for( $i = 0; **$lines[$i]**; $i++ )
```

Second step of **for** loop should be condition which is missing here

Comment: technical it is a condition, the variable can be true or false or something like that

Comment: Yes..agree..i want to show error in code..wrong words..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should define the $lines array before using in the for loop.

```
$lines[] = array(1,2,3,4,5);
for( $i = 0; $lines[$i]; $i++ ) /** LINE 9 **/
{
 print 'hai'; print PHP_EOL;
}
```

here, the "hai" would print 5 times from $lines[0] to $lines[4]. and the next it will return the same error, because there is no data on the $lines[5]

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the foreach for this purpose

```
foreach($lines as $key=>$line)
{
 /* your code here */

}
```

if you want to do this with for loop try this one

```
for( $i = 0; $i<count($lines); $i++ ) /** LINE 9 **/
{
if( $_POST['Aut'] == rtrim($lines[$i]) )
{
    fwrite($file, $_POST['addition']."\n\t");
    fwrite($file, $_POST['Aut'].PHP_EOL);

}
else
{
    fwrite($fd,$lines[$i]);
}
```